# IOS 13 Ruble currency symbol missing. Shows empty square instead

Tags: iphone, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, ios13

After a recent IOS 13 update a Ruble currency symbol disappeared from all my WordPress sites that use woocommerce when browsing from Iphones. It just shows an empty rectangle. I tried to fix that with adding a custom symbol through functions.php but with no luck so far. Is there a way to fix that? Thank you for your answers!

**EDIT**

Well i ve just found a solution. The issue is that this Ruble symbol is in the latin extended set of google fonts. When i changed my standard body fonts from wordpress options to google roboto font with latin extended set - all is back to normal. Thanks to everyone!)))

Comment: It's not possible to advise you without a link to the site or page where the error appears. However you can try deactivating all plugins to see if that helps, often times such issues arise due to caching plugins.

Comment: i ve tried deactivating all plugins - no effect. I actually noticed that this Ruble sign is missing also from wiki page dedicated to it, and some other websites that use this symbol. But it is visible on other sites. So i am completely lost in thoughts - whether it is an IOS 13 issue or certain websites issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that this Ruble symbol is in the Latin extended set of Google fonts.

When I changed my standard body fonts from Wordpress options to Google Roboto font with Latin extended set, all was back to normal.