# iOS 13 not displaying Russian Ruble (₽) unicode symbol

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode, applet, ios13

I'm having issues displaying the ₽ symbol on iOS 13.x.x.  It seems to be working on on iOS12, but when I use a device that had 13 installed, the unicode character shows up as an empty square.

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20bd/browsertest.htm

- Everything works fine on desktop
- iOS 12 renders the character properly
- iOS 13 renders empty square
- When I set the CSS font-family to only a few options ('system-ui' is one), the character displays properly

To compare these, opened an empty tab and only added the symbol to the body of the HTML.  This issue persisted.  Just to be clear, when I have no CSS or extra markup on the page, this issue is showing up.  Has anyone run into this? Did Apple remove unicode characters from some of their fonts?

iOS12:

[image]

iOS13:

[image]

Comment: Tried using ₽ from `Emoji & Symbol` keyboard?

Comment: what custom font are you using?

Comment: @VadimNikolaev `Helvetica`. Not custom

Comment: @user7128475 [on simulator is ok for iOS 13.3](https://ibb.co/6rhzJWT), do you use real device?

Comment: @VadimNikolaev Yes I noticed this on my own iPhone on a blank page with no styles attached

Comment: My html is `<html><head></head><body> ₽ </body></html>`

Comment: Yep, I've reproduced it for `WKWebView`. I guess it's an Apple's bug, because I see the same situation with ₼ symbol

Comment: Have you tried using the HTML escape instead of directl/y including the unicode character - ie `<html><head></head><body>&#8381;</body></html>`?

Comment: @samdy1Yes, same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finished my research and I'd like to say that the issue is exclusively in iOS and `WKWebView`. After an update to 13 version, iOS stopped recognizing a Ruble symbol  `₽` and, for example, Azerbaijani manat `₼` and Check Mark Unicode Character (`\u{2713}`) in certain font sets.

This issue affected thousands of web pages even huge brands. So just changing a font to specific ones solved the issue, but it's an workaround sure.

the same issues for iOS13: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120260/ios-13-ruble-currency-symbol-missing-shows-empty-square-instead), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389037/ruble-currency-symbol-missing-in-a-string-in-ios-13)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, weird that they dropped support.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround you can wrap separately the ruble sign in a font containing it. `Helvetica Neue` - contains the ruble sign ans it's [preinstalled IOS font](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/). For PC users you can use your default font like fallback.

```css
span.ruble-icon {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="ruble-icon">₽</span>
```

Comment: The asker has said in their comments that they're using Helvetica already. Could you explain why this will work around the problem in your answer?

Comment: Experimentally established that "Helvetica" does not have a ruble symbol, and "Helvetica Neue" has

Comment: @user7128475 You can not connect this font, it is a system IOS font.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also faced this, iOS 13 not displaying Russian Ruble (₽) Unicode symbol :- 
It's the default font on Macs, but rare on PCs. Since it's not technically web-safe, some people may have it and some people may not. If you want to use a font like that, without using @font-face, you may want to write it out in several different ways because it might not work the same for everyone."Helvetica Neue" it's working for me better try this 
example:font-family: "Helvetica-Cyrillic", "Helvetica", "Helvetica Neue" ;